# Is Neo Life business Good Islamically?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, sharia

I want to start a business Called Neo Life.

The Neo life Business is MLM company (GNLD)

The company promise us Three Things;
Use the Product
Share The Product
Share the Opportunity.

And They promise us Three things if can do that for them.
Sound Health
Cool Wealth
Freedom & Lifestyle.

The share the opportunity is must to build a generational wealth.
I will be prospecting to build my team.

For example, If I buy the product and sell or share it and gain a lot of profit there.

Someone I refer will also share or sell the product and gain his/her profit. Then, The company will now compensate me with a bonus. That would be stop my down line income.

So, I would be earn depends  on I build my team. And Someone I refer can Overtake me in the business when he refers people than me.

Please Halal or Haram in Islam?

Comment: Even if it were halal, it is certainly a scam, and you are the target. Will you be the 99% who spend more than they earn or nearly so? Or the 1% who can actually make a living from it? What is the safest assumption?